# How to model address relationships in NoSQL

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I want to model a relationship where I have an address (full details) and all the variations of this address.

```
For example all three adddress below
12345 Hickory Lane #2345 NC 9893
12345 Hickory Lane Apt 2345 NC - 9893
1234 Hickory Lane Apt NC 9893

will resolve to

12345 Hickory Lane Apt No 2345 LanesBorough, NC Postal Cod 9893
```

Writes look like this: Add a variation and its related full address
Reads look like this: Given a variation I would like to get its full address.

I can model this in a traditional SQL database using an DetailedAddress Table, which contains the full address and a Variations table which contains the variation that was queried for with reference to the Detailed address table

```
Detailed Address
Address Col1 | Address Col2 |... Postal Code

Variation
Detailed AddressId | VariationAddressString
```

I cant wrap my head around how to model this in a NoSQL database. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
Kay